# java.lang.NumberFormatException is there a better way around this issure?

Tags: android, numberformatexception

Here is my Java file for my app that I am working on.  The in logcat it is saying there is an error in the initvar() method in this line "length1et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlength1);"  I know this is because there is not a variable in the edittext box and I have had this problem before and just put 0's there to start out.  Is there a simple command to have nothing there and it will just understand to automatically put in a 0 for the value or is the only way to write some code to treat it as a zero?  Below the java code is the xml if that is necessary.  In a previous app I have just had it read the edittext box and if nothing is there, set the value to 0 before it does anything else.  For the record I know I don't have a button to call the calculate() method I just haven't put that in yet.

```
package com.example.constructioncalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Paint extends Activity {

    int numwin, numdoor;
    double areadoor, areawin, lengthft, lengthin, widthft, widthin, heightft,
            heightin, areawall, areaceil, paintcon, paintneeded;
    EditText length1et, length2et, width1et, width2et, height1et, height2et,
            paintconet, paintneededet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paintdisp);

        initvar();
        calculate();
        output();

    }

    private void initvar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        numwin = 0;
        numdoor = 0;
        areawin = 20;
        areadoor = 19.5;
        lengthft = 0;
        lengthin = 0;
        widthft = 0;
        widthin = 0;
        heightft = 0;
        heightin = 0;
        areawall = 0;
        areaceil = 0;
        paintcon = 0;
        paintneeded = 0;

        length1et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlength1);
        length2et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlength2);
        width1et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etwidth1);
        width2et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etwidth2);
        height1et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etheight1);
        height2et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etheight2);
        paintconet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpaintcon);
        paintneededet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpaintneeded);



    }

    private void calculate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    lengthft = Double.parseDouble(length1et.getText().toString());  
        lengthin = Double.parseDouble(length2et.getText().toString());
        widthft = Double.parseDouble(width1et.getText().toString());
        widthin = Double.parseDouble(width2et.getText().toString());
        heightft = Double.parseDouble(height1et.getText().toString());
        heightin = Double.parseDouble(height2et.getText().toString());
        paintcon = Double.parseDouble(paintconet.getText().toString());

        areaceil = (lengthft + lengthin / 12) * (widthft + widthin / 12);
        areawall = areaceil * (heightft + heightin / 12) - (numwin * areawin)
                - (numdoor * areadoor);
        paintneeded = (areawall / paintcon) * 1.1;

    }

    private void output() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        paintneededet.setText(String.valueOf(paintneeded));
    }

}
```

*************Here is my xml file...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Paint Coverage Estimator"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="@string/paintinst" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvlength"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Length"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwidth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Width"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvheight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Height"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etlength1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="feet"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etlength2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="inches"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etwidth1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="feet"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etwidth2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="inches"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etheight1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="feet"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etheight2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="inches"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="approx paint coverage (ft^2)?" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etpaintcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="300" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Paint needed of your buckets" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etpaintneeded"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If it depends on user input , then why don't you restrict or validate the input ?

Comment: That line has nothing wrong with it. What is the error you're getting? You should be able to have an empty EditText without it throwing errors, which leads me to believe the true error is elsewhere.

Comment: You are trying to parse an empty string `""`. From your onCreate(), you call `initvar()` and `calculate()`. But, the `EditTexts` do not have any text, hence the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I realize what the error is I was just wondering if there was an easier way to fix the error instead of always having a 0 there.  Is there a command to make android not care if there is a zero there?  Or is there another way to get the text to where I can leave it empty if i want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lengthft = Double.parseDouble(length1et.getText().toString()+0);
```

But be aware, if the user type in a invalid number and click on the button you haven't implemented yet, your app will crash. So you should probably add a check to all the EditText's before you call calculate().

Or even better, add a function to do it for you:

```
lengthft = getDouble(length1et); 



public double getDouble(EditText et) {

    if (!et.getText().equals(null)) {
        return Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString()); //convert your string into integer 
    } else {
        return 0; // or what you want to return if string is Null
    }
}
```